# Mongoose: Using $in operator with a JSON object

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am newbie to Nodejs and mongodb.

I was trying to get data for the following scenario. Consider 3 schemas as follows
Profile schema

```
var ProfileSchema = new Schema({
username: {type: String, match: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$/, unique: true},
name: String});
```

Posts schema

```
var PostsSchema = new Schema({
profileid: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Profile'},
message: {type: String, match: /^.{1,160}$/} });
```

Follows schema

```
var FollowSchema = new Schema({
profileid: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Profile'},
followingid: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Profile'}});
```

Which is similar to the twitter hierarchy.

To get all the posts from my followers I tried the following

```
Follows.find({'profileid' : '500d18823e792d8814000001'}).select('followingid -_id').limit(20).sort({addedon: 'desc'}).execFind(function (arr,followings) {
    Posts.find({profileid: {$in: followings}}).limit(20).execFind(function (arr,data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

But it is not working.
Please guide the best way to get this.

Thanks for your support

Comment: For starters, you're querying the Follows collection on the 'userid' field, but that doesn't appear to be in your schema.  Is the FollowsSchema you display in the question the entire Schema?

Comment: @shelman My bad, it is profileId in the query not userID.

Comment: What is `select('followingid -_id')`, I think it should be `select('followingid')`

Answer (score 1):

Are you not getting anything back from the initial query on the Follows collection?  You're passing in a string

```
'500d18823e792d8814000001'
```

as the profileId, but MongoDB stores strings and ObjectIds differently.  Since the profileid field is an ObjectId, you have to convert the string to an ObjectId before executing the query.

Try querying the Follows collection for

```
'profileid':ObjectId('500d18823e792d8814000001')
```